# How to select main item row from table using CASE WHERE conditions?

Tags: mysql, case

I have an array of products and I need to select the main photo of each product. My photo table consists of columns: id, product_id, photoname, flag, order.

'flag' = 1 when is the main photo and 'order' is the ordering of photos. Sometimes the 'flag' and 'order'are 0 (not set), so I need to assume the main photo is its 'id' ASC.

In my MySQL code I have:

```
private function getProducts($idUser) {

        $products = DB::connection('mysql2')->select("SELECT 
        a.*
        , (CASE WHEN photos.flag = 0 THEN 
            (
            SELECT photoname 
            FROM mpy_product_photos 
            WHERE flag = 1 AND product_id = a.id LIMIT 1
            ) 
            ELSE photos.photoname END
        ) AS photoname
        FROM mpy_products AS `a` 
        LEFT JOIN mpy_product_photos AS `photos` ON (photos.product_id = a.id) 
        WHERE a.user_id = '$idUsuario' 
        GROUP BY a.id 
        ORDER BY a.date DESC");

        return $products;

    }
```

When 'flag' = 0 for all 'photoname' from the same 'product_id', the return is null.

I've tried adding the following, along with many things but always get a Syntax error.

```
        , (CASE WHEN photos.flag = 0 THEN 
            (
            SELECT photoname 
            FROM mpy_product_photos 
            WHERE flag = 1 AND product_id = a.id LIMIT 1
            ) 
            ELSE 
            (
            SELECT photoname 
            FROM mpy_product_photos 
            WHERE product_id = a.id ORDER BY photos.id LIMIT 1 END
            ) 
        ) AS photoname
```

So when I don't have 'flag' = 1, I need to select and order by 'order' ASC. If 'order' = 0 in all rows, I need to select by 'id' ASC.

I've also tried the following, and at least I get a 'photoname' randomly (I guess) selected instead of null when all 'flag' = 0.

```
        , (CASE WHEN photos.flag = 0 THEN 
            (
            SELECT photoname 
            FROM mpy_product_photos 
            WHERE product_id = a.id ORDER BY photos.flag DESC LIMIT 1
            ) 
            ELSE photos.photoname END
        ) AS photoname
```

How can I solve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

UPDATE: You specifically ask for a solution with CASE WHEN. In the meantime, I provide alternatives.

For MySQL 5.5+

```sql
select 
    a.*,
    (select 
         photoname
     from my_product_photos
     where product_id = a.id
     order by flag desc, ord asc, id asc
     limit 1) as photoname
from my_product a;
```

If you're using MySQL 8.0, you can achieve this with the [RANK window function](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html#function_rank) rather simply as well

```sql
SELECT
    product.*,
    photo.photoname
FROM my_product product
    JOIN (
        SELECT 
            *,
            RANK() OVER(PARTITION BY product_id ORDER BY flag DESC, ord ASC, id ASC) AS r
        FROM my_product_photos
    ) photo ON photo.product_id = product.id AND photo.r = 1;
```

The RANK Function, as it's name implies, ranks the rows according to the given "rules". In the query, the rules are: Rank those with the higher `flag`, the lower `order` and lower `id` of the same `product_id`. This is going to be as a column of alias `r`. Then, you can just `INNER JOIN` as usual. With `r` you can then filter out the ones "less likely to be what you want".

This is a [DB Fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=cd349fa36c8789edb68c818b4f0ef26b) with sample data. This might not match what you have in your own DB, so adjust as necessary.

Comment: Thanks, now it's working. I used your first solution for MySQL 5.5+ as it is faster to implement on the bunch of routes I have using this code. My BD is mariaDB 10.4.